# How to generate 500ms and 700ms pulse using Arduino Nano V3?

Tags: arduino

I want to generate 500ms and 700ms pulses using an arduino Nano v3 simultaneously. How can I do this with accuracy, while also reading temperature from a thermistor as well?

Comment: When you say `500ms pulse`, you mean a signal that stays high for 500ms? Or a Dirac delta every 500ms?

Comment: A pulse which stays on for 500ms and off for 500ms. Same for 700ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use interrupts.

Make an interrupt every 100ms (has to be a divisor of 500, 700 and any period you want to use).

Inside the interrupt increment a variable.

When variable reach a multiple of 5 switch the output of the first signal. when it's a multiple of 7 switch the output of the second signal.